# How to change images when navigate into next fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to design a guide section in my app using fragments. I'm using 6 fragments in my GuidActivity.java which related to its activity activity_guid.xml , the activity contains coordenator layout which contains an image of dotsat the bottom, I want when I navigate into next fragment the image get changed to another image (the next image has yellow second dot ) and so on , any help or more simple idea to preview the progress of fragments ??

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ViewPager` instead, you will have gesture support and `onPageChanged` triggered when you scroll to next page.

A simple Onboarding screen doesn't need to use fragments

Comment: Is there a simple example of this please

Comment: There are lots of `ViewPager` tutorial online that you can find. A simplest way is to use a library for onboarding: try this https://github.com/Ramotion/paper-onboarding